# How to show that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$. Suppose also that $f(x)=g(x)$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$. Show that infact $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

There every some results I had proved in doing metric space that $E=\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$ is a closed set(I don't know if I can use this fact in this problem or not). I think I have to use the compactness of $[a,b]$ somehow which I couldn't figure out. Any hint will be enough. Thank you.

Comment: Hint : $f-g$ is also continous and you have to show $f(x)-g(x)\equiv 0$

Comment: If $f(c)=g(c)+\epsilon$ for some $c \in [a,b]$ and some $\epsilon>0$ then by continuity  $f(x)>g(x)+\frac12\epsilon$ in some neighbourhood of $c$

Comment: Thank you for your hint @peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f - g$ is continuous since $f, g$ are. By continuity then $(f-g)^{-1}([a, b]\setminus \{0\})  = \{x : f(x) \not = g(x)\}$ is open.

But the latter is of measure $0$ (as $f \equiv g$ a.e); every non empty open set has measure $>0$. So it must be empty, i.e, $f = g$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{x\in [a,b],f(x)\neq g(x)\}$, then $A$ is an open subset of $[a,b]$ because $f-g$ is continuous. If $A\neq\emptyset$, let $x\in A$, since $A$ is open there exists $\delta>0$ such that $]x-\delta,x+\delta[\subset A$, thus $\lambda(A)\geqslant 2\delta>0$ which is not because $\lambda(A)=0$ ($f=g$ a.e.). Therefore $A=\emptyset$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.